# I can't figure out how to make a each

Tags: html, jquery, handlebars.js, mustache

I tried to make it where each time you post a name and description, you will create a new div; however, it would only appear in the same div. Is there some way to prevent that from happening

```
<script id="churches" type="text/templete">
      <div class='settlement'>
        {{#ace}}
          <span>{{.}}</span>
        {{/ace}}
        <br/>
        {{#base}}
          <span>{{.}}</span>
        {{/base}}
        <button>like</button><button>comment</button>
      </div>
    </script>
```

This is the JavaScript to look into in case I made a mistake in it.

```
let churhy = (function () {
let shrine = ['title']
let token = ['Example']


let $b = $('#buildReligion');
let $nameR = $b.find('#rName');
let $describeR = $b.find('#dName');
let $enter = $b.find('#sunmit');
let churchTemplate = $('#churches').html();
let $placer= $('.u-religion');

$enter.on('click', addName);
$enter.on('click', addBase);
_render()

function _render() {
    $placer.html(Mustache.render(churchTemplate, {ace: shrine, base: token} ))      
}
function addName(value) {
    let symbol = typeof value === "string" ? value :$nameR.val();
    shrine.push(symbol);
    _render();        
    $nameR.val('');
}
function addBase(worth) {
     let describe = typeof worth === "string" ? worth :$describeR.val();
     token.push(describe);
     _render();
     $describeR.val('');
}
return {
    addName: addName,
    addBase: addBase
};
```

})();

Comment: https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#each

Comment: If you want a `<div>` per item in the `#each` block, then the `<div>` must be placed within the `#each` block. You have two `#each` blocks, so you might want to consider merging your two arrays into one.